# Generate generic getters and setters for entity properties using decorators

Tags: typescript

I am translating my model entities to Typescript (where they get populated using an ajax call). I would like each to have a basic getter and setter for each property in my entity:

```
entity.setProductID("2r3e4r4t5y6t5y6") and entity.getProductID()
```

Currently, I'm defining those methods for each property in the class

```
   /**
    *@name "productID"
    *@ormtype "string"
    *@length "32"
    *@fieldtype "id"
    *@generator "uuid"
    *@unsavedvalue ""
    */
    private productID: string;

    getProductID():string { return this.productID; }
    setProductID(productID:string) { this.productID = productID; }
```

But I have roughly 30 - 80 properties per entity and 150 entities, so the code is a bit verbose with getter and setter definitions.

To solve that, I was hoping to use a decorator @generateGetterAndSetter that I could decorate each property with that would dynamically generate the getter and setter for me. Which looks like:

```
@generateGetterAndSetter
private productID: string;
```

To accomplish that I defined the decorator and added it to my module:

```
/** decorate the property to attach a getter and setter */
function generateGetterAndSetter(target: any, key: string) {

  // property value
  var _val = this[key];

  // property getter
 var getMethodName = 'get' + key.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + key.slice(1);
 var setMethodName = 'set' + key.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + key.slice(1);

  /** Build the getter and setter functions dynamically */
  var getter = new Function("return function " + getMethodName + "(){  return _val;}")();
  var setter = new Function("return function " + setMethodName + "(newVal){  _val = newVal;}")();

  target[getMethodName] = getter;
  target[setMethodName] = setter;

  Object.defineProperty(target, key, {
      get: getter,
      set: setter,
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true
  });
}//<--end generateGetterAndSetterDefinition
```

From the above code, you can see that I've tried both Object.defineProperty as well as manually adding the functions to target. But in testing this with:

```
var product = new Product();
product.setProductID("123456789");  
product.setProductName("Generic Shoes");
product.setUrlTitle("http://some/brand/get");   

console.log("Product: ", product.getProductName(), product.getProductID(), product.getUrlTitle());
```

It produces the incorrect result:

```
Product: http://some/brand/get http://some/brand/get http://some/brand/get
```

rather than the expected

```
Product: Generic Shoes 123456789 http://some/brand/get
```

Which is surely because I'm overwriting the definition on each assignment. Is there a better way to solve this without having to include a get/set method for each property while still maintaining the proper function naming convention of getPropertyName() and setPropertyName(value)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check `window._val`, you will see that it will be equal to `http://some/brand/get` after running the code. So all the functions are reading and writing from the same variable because the scope with `var _val` is lost when doing `new Function("...");`.

You should instead just define the functions right on the object's prototype—`target`:

```
function generateGetterAndSetter(target: Object, key: string) {
    var getMethodName = 'get' + key.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + key.slice(1);
    var setMethodName = 'set' + key.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + key.slice(1);

    target[getMethodName] = function() {
        return this[key];
    };
    target[setMethodName] = function(val) {
        this[key] = val;
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was overthinking it and got lost. This is the correct answer and it works great!

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea about ts. But JavaScript now has the [proxies](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-proxy-constructor) since ES2015 (aka "ES6") specification. Proxies let you create objects that are true proxies for (facades on) other objects.

```
var obj = new Proxy({}, {
get: function(target, name) {
    if (!(name in target)) {
        console.log("Getting non-existant property '" + name + "'");
        return undefined;
    }
    return target[name];
},
set: function(target, name, value) {
    if (!(name in target)) {
        console.log("Setting non-existant property '" + name + "', initial value: " + value);
    }
    target[name] = value;
    return true;
}
});

console.log("[before] obj.foo = " + obj.foo);
obj.foo = "bar";
console.log("[after] obj.foo = " + obj.foo);
```

Comment: Thanks for this I had not heard of proxies. Is it possible to bind the `this` context or pass any extra arguments into the handler? I want to access methods on outside classes from inside the handler.

Comment: I have added a question on this FWIW: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64996534/is-is-possible-to-pass-this-context-into-an-es6-proxy-handler