# Is it possible to pass parameters into an ES6 `Proxy' handler?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to override base settings with custom settings and the [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) object seemed like an ideal solution.

```js
  settingsHandler = {
    get(target, property) {
        return this.getSettings(property) || target[property];
    }
  }
  this.settings = new Proxy(baseSettings, settingsHandler);
```

but the `this` context inside the handler is just the `target` object, and `this.getSettings(property)` fails because it is not available.

Seems like `Proxy` is not meant for this but I cannot find that stated unequivocally. Perhaps I should make a class instead?

Comment: In what context is `getSettings()` defined? Can you show us more code? Perhaps `this` is not needed.

Comment: @OskarGrosser this is pseudocode as the project is too complicated to show here. I have posted an answer, what do you think?

Comment: You could capture `this` in scope `const nameIt = this; this.settings = new Proxy(..., { get(target, prop} { return nameIt.getSettings(prop) || target[prop]})`

Comment: You can use an arrow function: `settingsHandler = { get: (target, property) => { … } };`

Comment: "*I want to override base settings with custom settings and the `Proxy` object seemed like an ideal solution.*" - no, it's not. Just create a normal settings object and overwrite them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On considering the helpful advice, the simplest solution that fit my needs was to use arrow function syntax:

```js
const settingsHandler = {
  get: (target, property) => {
      return this.getSettings(property) || target[property];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jasuperior/807ace24838ca5b45fe42d8e5d36f420) which helped me get the functionality I wanted by wrapping the `Proxy` inside a `Class` and having the `settings` object be a property of that class:

```js
export default class ProxySettings extends Object {
  token: Token;
  settings: TokenSettings;

  constructor(token, settings) {
    super(...arguments);
    this.token = token;
    this.settings = settings;
    return new Proxy(this, this.handler);
  }
  get handler() {
    return {
      get(target, property) {
        return target.token.getSettings(property) || target.settings[property];
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Which is instantiated like so: `this.settings = new ProxySettings(this.token, baseTokenSettings);`

Works well but it is a little messy and I haven't seen this pattern before so I am somewhat unsure if this is the best way to do this. Any input appreciated.

Comment: This looks like OOP for the sake of OOP. You could have say `function overrideSettings(token, settings){ return new Proxy(settings, { get(target, value)() {/* just use token here */}}}` no need for `this` and yet another class.

Comment: No, you shouldn't wrap the `Proxy` around a class. At best, you can make the `handler` object a class instance.